# What is the obstruction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, deformation-theory

(This is from Chapter I.2 of Kollar's "Rational curves on algebraic varieties".)

Let $B$ be an extension of $A$: $0\rightarrow J\rightarrow B\rightarrow A\rightarrow 0$, $A$ and $B$ both being Noetherian local rings with residue field $k$. Let $T$ be a $k$-algebra, $I \subset T$ and ideal, $Q=T/I$, and 
$$R\xrightarrow r G\xrightarrow g I\rightarrow 0 \tag{1}$$ a presentation of $I$ by free $T$-modules.

Let $T^B$ be Noetherian, flat over $B$ such that $T^B\otimes_B k \cong T$, and the $m_B$-adic topology on $T^B$ is separated. Let $T^B\otimes_B A \cong T^A$. Let $I^A \subset T^A$ be an ideal such that $Q^A = T^A/I^A$ is flat over $A$.

We can lift (1) to an exact sequence of $T^A$ modules 
$$R^A\xrightarrow {r^A} G^A\xrightarrow {g^A} I^A\rightarrow 0. \tag{2}$$

Let $r^B$ and $g^B$ be any morphisms lifting $r^A$ and $g^A$ respectively. Then we have a commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
R^B @>{r^B}>> G^B @>{g^B}>> I^B @>>> 0 &\text{(not necessarily a complex!)}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
R^A @>{r^A}>> G^A @>{g^A}>> I^A @>>> 0 &\text{(exact row)}\\
\end{CD}

We can then define $e(g^B):R\rightarrow Q\otimes J$ independently on the choice of $r^B$, and we can write $$E(g^B) = \text{coker}[R\xrightarrow {e(g^B)+r} Q\otimes J + G]$$ as an extension
$$0\rightarrow Q\otimes J\rightarrow E(g^B) \rightarrow I \rightarrow 0.$$

It is said that we now obtain an element $E^B(Q^A) := [E(g^B)]\in \text{Ext}_T^1(I,Q\otimes J)$, which is called the obstruction.

Now finally here are my questions:

1. How do we obtain this element?
2. What does it stand for, intuitively? What does it "obstruct"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Equivalence_of_extensions

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The last sentence of that paragraph is a statement of the fact, which I am trying to understand the reason of.

Comment: The reference to Weibel given in the Wikipedia article is a good one. Alternatively you could get this material from Serge Lang's *Algebra*. But most probably there is also some online material covering this (it's all homological algebra, and certainly not deep).

Comment: Great, I found the construction in Lang. Care to comment on the second question?

Comment: The Ext class is an obstruction to the splitness of the short exact sequence. Concretely, and applied in your situation, this means: if $e:=[E(g^B)]$ is zero in the Ext group, then there is a map $I \to E(g^B)$ that is a section of $E(g^B) \to I$ (meaning the composition $I \to I$ is the identity), from which it follows that $E(g^B)$ is the direct sum of the outer terms $I$ and $Q \otimes J$; if $e \neq 0$, then there is no such section (which usually implies that the middle term is not isomorphic to the direct sum either, but that isn't what the theory gets you).